# gcd of 12 and 6

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Stpid question, I know, but I need to understand. As far as I know $\gcd(12, 6)$ is equal to $\gcd(6, 12)$. But, if I use extended euclidean algorithm I get:
$$\gcd(12, 6)\quad 12/6=2\quad12\%6=0$$
While if I swap the two integers:
$$\gcd(6,12)\quad 6/12=0\quad 6\%12=6$$
next step
$$12/6=2\quad 12\%6=0$$

So, in first case the one and only remainder that I get is $0$ (there is no remainders first of null remainder).
In the second place, first of null remainder there is $6$! What's the real $\gcd(12,6)$?

Comment: The greatest common divisor of $12$ and $6$ is $6$.

Comment: take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Euclid%27s_algorithm_Book_VII_Proposition_2_3.png to see why the euclidean algorithm works. You cant start out by dividing the smaller of the two with the larger.

Comment: @user996522: You can begin either way; you just have to know what you’re doing.

Comment: Given two (say positive, though that can be relaxed) positive integers $a \leq b,$ we set $r_{-1} = a, r_0 = b$ and we define $r_{n+1}$ inductively via $r_{n} = q_{n}r_{n-1} + r_{n+1},$ where $0 \leq r_{n+1} < r_{n-1}$ and $q_{n}$ is an integer. On the first occasion when $r_{n+1} =0,$ we have $r_{n-1} = {\rm gcd}(a,b).$ The real gcd is $6$ in your case. Remember that the gcd must divide both integers you start with

Comment: You might find this link helpful:
http://www.math.sc.edu/~sumner/numbertheory/euclidean/euclidean.html
You can enter 2 numbers and the page runs the extended Euclidean algorithm showing all of the intermediate steps.

Comment: You've got the same bottom-line answer either way: the gcd is $6$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you apply the Euclidean algorithm to $a$ and $b$, $\gcd(a,b)$ is the last **non-zero** remainder. If you begin by dividing $12$ into $6$, your steps are:

$$\begin{align*}
6&=12\cdot 0+6\\
6&=6\cdot 1+0\;.
\end{align*}$$

The last non-zero remainder is $6$, and indeed $\gcd(6,12)=6$. If you begin the other way round, your only step is

$$12=6\cdot 2+0\;.$$

You might think that there is no non-zero remainder here, but you have to remember that the **divisor** at each step is the **remainder** from the previous step. Thus, the divisor of $6$ should be thought of here as being the remainder from a virtual previous step, so that we have a non-zero remainder. Thus, once again the last non-zero remainder is $6=\gcd(12,6)$.

Answer (score 0):

this is not correct step, $\gcd(a,b)$ and $\gcd(b,a)$ are equal, but method that you described is not correct. Imagine that in one case $a<b$  but in other $b>a$  so  if you do so next time,you would be in trouble again.

Comment: Will I avoid all further troubles, using $gcd(a,b)$ and impose b>a?

Comment: you should  know  that,while  proof gcd(a,b)=gcd(b,a), no one  try to proof  is by  compare results,which you described in your question